# How do you make the overflow of the header take icons into account for jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

My question is similar to the one being asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003067/how-do-i-make-a-jquery-mobile-header-wrap-and-left-justified), but I am being more picky and wasn't quite satisfied with that answer.

I am working with jQuery mobile, and some of my titles in the header are too long to fit with the buttons I have added and get turned into ellipses. I am totally fine with that, except that it doesn't quite calculate the length to which it needs to trim correctly when there are icons in the buttons. The button with the icon slightly overlaps the beginning of the title.

I'm not sure if I explained that clearly, so here are some pictures (it looks like they may have gotten a bit distorted, but they still show what I'm talking about).

This is the "good" version. The title text is nicely cut off with ellipses and fits in between the two buttons.

[image: Good version]

In this version, however, the amount of space between the buttons is miscalculated because of the icon on the left and the left button overlaps the text.

[image: Bad version]

Is there a way through either JavaScript or CSS that I can fix the length of the text in between the buttons so that there is no overlap when I use an icon? Or do I just have to trade off having an icon or not having an overlap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following css

```
.ui-header .ui-title{
    margin-left:110px;
    margin-right:80px;
}
```

I modified the margin-right value because I felt it needs to some adjustment to the ellipsis placement.You can skip it or edit it if it is not needed.

A demo  - http://jsfiddle.net/YL8Ah/